# "backordered" text on Order Details and Email

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i need to change the "backordered" text on Order Details and on Emails to "Dropship".
i have already insert a code, but it only change text on single product page and cart, but not on Order details and on Order emails.

please Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on how you are changing the text? If you're using translations (or a translation plugin), make sure to get all these strings:

- `Backordered`
- `(can be backordered)`
- `%1$s units of %2$s have been backordered in order #%3$s.`